# Calling function with parameters gives two errors

Tags: c, variables

Errors I receive:

```
main.c:63:7: error: conflicting types for 'integrieren'
main.c:39:6: note: previous implicit declaration of 'integrieren' was here
```

Main.c:39:

```
        A = integrieren(dx,y);
```

with

```
float A,x[1001],y[1001],dx;
```

main.c:63:

```
float integrieren(float dx,float y[1001])
```

Comment: Please note, that this is one error and a note where should you look into, not two errors.

Answer (score 1):

You probably did not delcare `float integrieren(float dx,float y[1001])` before you tried to use it at `main.c:39`.

Default `c` behaviour is to *implicitly* declare the functions in such cases, however the types it assumes are `int`. Therefore you get one inmplicit declaration at `main.c:39` and one explicit at line 63, and the error. I think it's ansi-c behaviour, newer versions of standards would call it an error when calling undefined function and you would get "Undefined symbol `integrieren`" or something similar as an error (99% sure on it though).

Just forward declare `float integrieren(float dx,float y[1001]);` above line 39 in `main.c` probably it should lie in the global scope too.

Something like

```
#include<fancy_stuff.h>
#include<fancier_stuff.h>

float integrieren(float dx,float y[1001]); //declaration

int main(){
  //main stuff
  return 0;
}

//definition
float integrieren(float dx,float y[1001]){
  //body
}
```

Then compiler knows what `integrieren` call signature is. You do not need to *define* the body there, just declare it.

Answer (score 0):

On line 39 when you used integieren() without having prototyped it first, the compiler assumed its return type and all arguments were integers.

Either move the definition of integierer() above the place where it is called, or prototype it first.